# How to use types like this: type a = b -> c in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I want to create a type that stores name and value of a variable,so I did this:

```
type Variable = String
type Val = Int    
type Store = Variable -> Val
```

now, how can I use this Store?

for example I want to write a function(*fetch*) that returns value of a variable according to its *Store* or a function(*initial*) to initial all the variables( assign a default value,like 0):

```
fetch:: Store -> Variable -> Val
initial:: Store
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Looks to me like you want something like records. Note that `type` is only for aliasing types. You want perhaps `data`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Store` type is just an alias for a specific kind of function, I could write one as

```
constStore :: Store
constStore _ = 1
```

You could make a more complex one:

```
lenStore :: Store
lenStore var = length var
-- or
-- lenStore = length
```

Then `fetch` is just function application

```
fetch :: Store -> Variable -> Val
fetch store var = store var
```

Answer (score 4):

Stores are functions, so you can just apply the store to the variable:

```
fetch :: Store -> Variable -> Val
```

so

```
fetch :: (Variable -> Val) -> Variable -> Val
```

thus

```
fetch store var = store var
```

but that would be simpler written

```
fetch = id
```

or omitted altogether, so if `myStore :: Store`, I can do

```
myStore "myVariable"
```

and I'll get the appropriate value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `fetch = ($)`, not `fetch = id`.

Comment: @DMST The type of `id` is `t -> t`, all it does is return its argument.  If we look at the type of `Store`, it's `(Variable -> Val)`.  If you have a store `s :: Store`, then if you let `t ~ Store`, that's the same as saying `t ~ (Variable -> Val)`.  Then you get `id :: Store -> Store` is the same as `id :: (Variable -> Val) -> (Variable -> Val)`, and the second set of parens can be removed, leaving just `id :: (Variable -> Val) -> Variable -> Val`.  Substituting back, we get `id :: Store -> Variable -> Val`, which is the signature of `fetch`.  (`~` is type equality)

Comment: @AaditMShah Both will work, `($)` is basically just `id` as an infix operator with a different precedence.